# Unable to pass service annotations when deploying helm chart via terraform

Tags: terraform

I have seeing some examples regarding how to pass annotations when deploying a helm chart via terraform but none of then are working as expected,  in this case, im trying to create a service assining a private ip on a specific subnet, but instead, its creating a public IP.
My terraform files:

```
locals {
  helm_general = {
    # Reference values
    # https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/values.yaml
    elasticsearch = {
      name      = "elasticsearch"
      chart     = "elastic/elasticsearch"
      tag       = "7.14.0"
      namespace = "elasticsearch"
      set = [
        {
          name  = "nodeSelector.agentpool"
          value = "general"
        },      
        {
          name  = "replicas"
          value = "1"
        },
        {
          name  = "minimumMasterNodes"
          value = "1"
        },
        {
          name  = "image"
          value = "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
        },
        {
          name  = "imageTag"
          value = "7.14.0"
        },
        {
          name  = "resources.requests.cpu"
          value = "10m"
        },
        {
          name  = "resources.requests.memory"
          value = "128Mi"
        },
        {
          name  = "volumeClaimTemplate.reosources.requests.storage"
          value = "4Gi"
        },
        {
          name  = "persistence.enabled"
          value = "false"
        },
        {
          name  = "service.type"
          value = "LoadBalancer"
        },
        {
          name  = "service.annotations\\.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"
          value = "true"
        },
        {
          name  = "service.annotations\\.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet"
          value = "somesubnet"
        },          
      ]
      timeout = "900"
    }
  }
}
```

Helm deployment

```
resource "helm_release" "helm" {
  provider  = helm.general
  for_each  = local.helm_general
  name      = each.value.name
  chart     = each.value.chart
  namespace = format(each.value.namespace)
  dynamic "set" {
    iterator = item
    for_each = each.value.set == null ? [] : each.value.set

    content {
      name  = item.value.name
      value = item.value.value
    }
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.general]
}
```

Plan / apply output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NneuP.png

And what is currently being deployed is a public ip instead of a private ip:

```
Namespace:                elasticsearch                                                     
Labels:                   app=elasticsearch-master                                          
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm                                 
                          chart=elasticsearch                                               
                          heritage=Helm                                                     
                          release=elasticsearch                                             
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: elasticsearch                          
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: elasticsearch                     
Selector:                 app=elasticsearch-master,chart=elasticsearch,release=elasticsearch
Type:                     LoadBalancer                                                      
IP Families:              <none>                                                            
IP:                       xx                                                      
IPs:                      xxx                                                     
LoadBalancer Ingress:     redacted public ip                                                      
Port:                     http  9200/TCP                                                    
TargetPort:               9200/TCP                                                          
NodePort:                 http  32083/TCP                                                   
Endpoints:                                                                                  
Port:                     transport  9300/TCP                                               
TargetPort:               9300/TCP                                                          
NodePort:                 transport  32638/TCP                                              
Endpoints:                                                                                  
Session Affinity:         None                                                              
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster                                                           
Events:                                                                                     
  Type    Reason                Age        From                Message                      
  ----    ------                ----       ----                -------                      
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  1s         service-controller  Ensuring load balancer       
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   <invalid>  service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

References that i have been following:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/125
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

Edit:

error message:

```
Error: unable to decode "": resource.metadataOnlyObject.ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta.Annotations: ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|nternal":true},"labe|..., bigger context
..|beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal":true},"labels":{"app":"elasticsearch-master","chart|...

  with helm_release.helm["elasticsearch"],
  on aks-general-helm.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "helm":
   1: resource "helm_release" "helm" {
```

Comment: Please post the error message as part of the question. It seems to me that the error is not in the annotations but the module you are using seems to be missing one variable you are trying to set.

Comment: @MarkoE edited and update accordingly. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just faced a similar issue, and here is what worked for me:

```hcl
{
 name  = "service.annotations.service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"
 value = "true"
},
```

I think the issue is how it is concatenated. The service in the chart manifest for elastic official is `service.annotations:{}` so you need to append `.service` then use `\\`.

Comment: solved with exactly this approach a few months back :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this without the escape characters and keeping the original YAML format would be using [values](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#values) attribute of the `helm_release` resource. Would be curious to know if there was a specific used-case to not use it in the first place.

```
resource "helm_release" "helm" {
  provider  = helm.general
  for_each  = local.helm_general
  name      = each.value.name
  chart     = each.value.chart
  namespace = format(each.value.namespace)

  values = each.value.values ##CHANGE IS HERE ##

  dynamic "set" {
    iterator = item
    for_each = each.value.set == null ? [] : each.value.set

    content {
      name  = item.value.name
      value = item.value.value
    }
  }
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.general]
}
```

The local in your case would be adjusted to below, you can still keep set for something which has a dependency on any terraform resources or with any other logical reasons.

```
locals {
  helm_general = {
    # Reference values
    # https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/values.yaml
    elasticsearch = {
      [...]
      values = [file("${path.module}/elasticsearch-values.yaml")]
      [...]
    }
  }
}
```

There has to be a new file `elasticsearch-values.yaml` at the same path (which can be adjusted with any relative path as per the `local.helm_general.elasticsearch.values`) location, where this terraform configurations exist.

```yaml
# Reference values can be adapted as per the upstream chart.
# https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/values.yaml
service:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "somesubnet"
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have multiple you can try something like this, pass annotations as map and set them using

```html
  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = var.ingress_annotations
    content {
      name = replace(set.key, ".", "\\.")
      value = set.value
    }
  }
```